# Ordering files with grunt-neuter

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I've created an ember app with yeoman and am trying to get the build to order the scripts. I have an app.coffee which contains `require 'scripts/controllers/*'` but I also need to order the scripts within controllers. I have something like this:

**controllers/foo_controller.js.coffee**

```
require "./bar_controller"
App.FooController = App.BarController.extend()
```

**controllers/bar_controller.js.coffee**

```
App.BarController = Ember.Controller.extend()
```

But it isn't ordering these files. Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this, I had the relative path wrong. It should have looked like this:

```
require "scripts/controllers/bar_controller"
App.FooController = App.BarController.extend()
```

Comment: is this the only logical solution